# Axigen Disable 550 Messages

Tags: smtp, message

I was performing some SPAM Testing on an Axigen Server, when I discovered a flaw which I would like to know if it can be disabled.

On the System I was testing, the Server will spit out 550 Error messages whenever an invalid User is passed as an RCPT TO: Argument.

Example:

```
MAIL FROM: <Test@Mail.com>
250 Sender Accepted

RCPT TO: InvalidUser
550 User Not Found

RCPT TO: ValidUser
250 Recipient Accepted
```

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the 550 Messages, as this would allow an attacker to discover valid usernames.

Thank you,

Andrew Borg

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible - you could configure the 'catch all' option for each domain where you like to have this behavior.